# python : local variable is referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Here is my code :

```
x = 1
def poi(y):
        # insert line here

def main():
    print poi(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If following 4 lines are placed, one at a time, in place of  `# insert line here`

```
 Lines         | Output
---------------+--------------
1. return x    | 1 
2. x = 99      |
   return x    | 99
3. return x+y  | 2 
4. x = 99      | 99
```

**In above lines it seems that global x declared above function is being used in case 1 and 3**

But ,

```
x = x*y      
return x
```

This gives

```
error : local variable 'x' is reference before assignment
```

What is wrong in here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to access a global variable, you can just access it by its name. But if you want to change its value, you need to use the keyword `global`.

try :

```
global x
x = x * y      
return x
```

In case 2, x is created as a local variable, the global x is never used.

```
>>> x = 12
>>> def poi():
...   x = 99
...   return x
... 
>>> poi()
99
>>> x
12
```

Comment: but in case 2) also its value is changed without being used global

Comment: No, in case 2, x is a local variable. I have updated my answer

Comment: x2 = x1 * y      return x2; cannot interpreter treat x1 as global and creates x2 as local ?

Comment: @naveenyadav Of yourse it can - if you name them distinctly. Using `x` and `x_local` would be fine, no matter how you name them actually.

Answer (score 6):

When Python sees that you are assigning to `x` it forces it to be a local variable name. Now it becomes impossible to see the global `x` in that function (unless you use the `global` keyword)

So

Case 1) Since there is no local `x`, you get the global

Case 2) You are assigning to a local `x` so *all* references to `x` in the function will be the local one

Case 3) No problem, it's using the global `x` again

Case 4) Same as case 2